# Is there a way to count rows in SQL Server that only count rows with identical information once?

Tags: sql-server, count

For example let's say this is my data:

```
PK       FNAME  LNAME
------------------------
2         Fred  SEG
3         Fred  SEG
4         Dave  Smith
```

I want to get a result of one Fred and one Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add distinct keyword.

```
select distinct fname, lname from table;
```

Comment: so that would still count fred and dave but skip the second fred? would this skip a data row like karen SEG?

Comment: thanks this worked in a small batch just need to try it in big

Answer (score 1):

Do you want `count(distinct)`?

```
select count(distinct fname)
from t;
```

If you actually want the *rows*, with names not repeated, then use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.pk = (select min(t2.pk) from t t2 where t2.fname = t.fname);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL COUNT function is an aggregate function that returns the number of rows returned by a query. You can use the **COUNT function** in the **SELECT statement** to get the number of employees, the number of employees in each department, the number of employees who hold a specific job, etc.

**COUNT(*)**

The COUNT(*) function returns the number of rows in a table including the rows that contain the NULL values.

**Table employees:**

1. Employee_Id
2. First_Name
3. Last_Name
4. Email
5. Phone_Number
6. Salary
7. Department_id

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees;